# Why doesn't foldr const 0 "tacos" Compile in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, fold

So `foldr const 0 "tacos"` should unravel to be something like

```
0 const ('t' const ('a' const ('c' const ('o' const 's')))).
```

I think it would just stop at `0 const ('t'` though because Haskell is lazy evaluated and const just takes the first argument. So, in theory, wouldn't the function turn out to apply to 1?

This doesn't work though. And replacing `0` with `""` doesn't work either. Does anyone know why?

Thank you!

Comment: Because the types do not make sense. First of all `0 const ...` makes no sense, but even then it would mean that depending on the length of the list, the signature is different. Whereas the signature is *static* (known at compile time).

Comment: `foldr :: Foldable t => (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b`. Or, a simplified version of its type that can be used a list like `"tacos"`, `foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b`. Which types should Haskell use for `a` and `b` in the case of `foldr const 0 "tacos"`? Does that match up with the type of `const`?

Comment: `fodlr const 'a' "tacos"` does work though, and produces `'t'` as you expect - and the same for any character in place of `'a'`. You simply have to supply a "starting accumulator" which is the same type as the type in the list - here, that means a character.

Comment: Can I interest you in `foldr (flip const) 0 "tacos"`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing you made two errors: one small and one slightly less small.

1. To use a variable with letters (such as `const`) as an operator, you must enclose it in backticks:

   ```
   "hello" `const` 1 = "hello"
   "hello" const 1 -- nonsense
   ```
2. You partially mixed up `foldr` with `foldl`:

   ```
   foldr (#) n [1..3] = 1 # (2 # (3 # n))
   foldl (#) b [1..3] = ((b # 1) # 2) # 3
   ```

Indeed, `foldl` works just fine with `const`:

```
foldl const 0 "tacos"
  = ((((0 `const` t) `const` a) `const` c) `const` o) `const` s
  = 0
```

This silly calculation is rather inefficient—it needs to walk the whole list to apply `const 0` to each element, even though the result is always the same!

Comment: Thanks for acknowledging OP's intention to use `const` infix.

Answer (score 5):

> Why doesn't foldr const 0 “tacos” Compile in Haskell?

Because:

```
> foldr const 0 "tacos"

<interactive>:1:13: error:
    • No instance for (Num Char) arising from the literal ‘0’
    • In the second argument of ‘foldr’, namely ‘0’
      In the expression: foldr const 0 "tacos"
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = foldr const 0 "tacos"
```

So if we investigate we see (please ignore the `@[]`, its a type application to make our conversation simpler)

```
> :t foldr @[] const 0
foldr @[] const 0 :: Num b => [b] -> b
```

So you need to provide a list of items that are `Num` instances. But you provided:

```
> :t "tacos"
"tacos" :: [Char]
```

Tacos are sometimes tortillas wrapped around meat and rice.  But sometimes, such as now, they are lists of characters. Characters aren't instances of `Num`.  That's what the error is trying to tell you.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the type of foldr (and let's specialize to lists):

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
```

You have provided the arguments (and let's specialize to Int for the 0)

```
const :: a -> b -> b  -- this looks off...
0 :: b                -- this means b = Int
"tacos" :: [a]        -- this means a = Char
```

Hold on a second. Check the actual type of const:

```
const :: a -> b -> a
```

See the problem? You've got the arguments to `const` in the wrong order. Try `(flip const)` instead of `const` to get the desired answer, although it doesn't have the desired performance characteristics.

You may also want to try `foldl'` which accumulates the result from left to right.

---

In the way you've originally written it, the type system must unify const's type signature `a -> b -> a` with foldr's argument type `a -> b -> b`, which can only be done by unifying `a = b`. However since `a = Char` and `b = Int`, this unification cannot be performed.

The correct "unraveling" of your expression (the way `foldr` works) would be to replace the `:` with `const` and the `[]` with `0`.

```
't' : 'a' : 'c' : 'o' : 's' : []
==> let's write it with (:) as a prefix funtion
(:) 't' ((:) 'a' ((:) 'c' ((:) 'o' ((:) 's' [])))) 
==>
const 't' (const 'a' (const 'c' (const 'o' (const 's' 0))))
```

But with the restriction that all of the above `const` must have the same type, which they can't.

Notice how `0` appears in the *innermost* const, not the outermost.